# Styling of text objects in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, text

I need this workflow in Inkscape: many text objects of the same style, I change the style of one object, the style of all text objects changes the same way, but the text of all objects are different. I tried cloning, but the text is the same for all objects and can't be changed.

Comment: Are you sure you need Inkscape for such a task? It could be very simple with a wordprocessor using styles. In Inkscape, if the text is not part of a group, you can select all and change the style of the selected text objects. Or you can work at xml level. Can you tell us something more about your efforts and about the purpose of your styling?

Comment: I was experimenting with a single color for a bunch of different text objects. I can do  it for each object, but it is very time consuming, so I need solutions better than that.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the proposed answers?

Comment: You can change all objects of the same style. Mark one text object, and choose in the Edit-Menu "select same", "same object". But that's only an all-or-nothing approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the style or attributes of any objects in Inkscape you first need to select them. Unfortunately, Inkscape doesn't have a character styles panel like word processors or page layout software where you can define character styles.

So, with that in mind, here's a workaround.

Assuming your text is contained in separate text objects, select all the text objects you wish to change. You can click and drag with the Select and Transform Objects tool <kbd>F1</kbd>, or click on each object while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make a multiple selection, then hit the Text Tool <kbd>F8</kbd>. Finally change the styles you want in the Control Bar along the top.

[image]

Another possible workaround is to copy one text object which has a style you want, then select the others then hit *Edit > Paste Style <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>*

[image]

Comment: So well presented - you are my hero Billy.

Answer (score 1):

Or try to right-click on a text, then choose 'Select same' > 'Object type' to select all texts in the current document. Then you can change their style.